# doGet() parameter handling in templates

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

I have a problem passing parameters from a doget() to a template im using with Google Apps Script. Here's an code excerpt:

The .gs file:

```
  function doGet(request) {
  var t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');
  t.line = findCell(request)
  t.parameters = request
  return t.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}
```

The .html file:

```
 <?= parameters.id ?>
```

If I then go to this URL (of the actual app) https://script.google.com/a/macros/bucerius-alumni.de/s/AKfycbwvpTfB8KeMIUex4XUiWyI5qHfDbrNb-ZUHbgFJcsikFjuRo9WV/exec?id=1 and pass the parameter id=1 it renders out 'undefined'.

I don't really get it.

Comment: Have you tried if it works with `HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE` instead of `IFRAME`?

Answer (score 1):

URL parameters are received in `doGet` under a "parameter" property of the first function parameter, in your case `request`. So, it would be `request.parameter.id`. Or in your html `parameters.parameter.id`.

To see all the parameters you receive and their structure, change your html to:

```
<?= JSON.stringify(parameters) ?>
```