# How do I code a doGet(e) function to get an array of name/values?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

I have a Web App example, from a [tutorial](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/turn-your-google-sheet-into-a-web-application-f766f1ff8b98) using `doPost(e)`, which uses `var body = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents)` to append rows from the request to a Google sheet.

However I want to use `doGet(e)`, but I haven't yet found out how to write the equivalent code.

Comment: Please start by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web, then read the tags wikis and spend some time searching for helpful content from this site. If you still need help add a brief description of your most relevant findings from this site explaining why didn't help you and show what you have tried direclty into the question body as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Thanks, I did. Apologies if I don't meet the standards!

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29258873/paramter-handleing-google-apps-script-doget-in-templates) answer that says *URL parameters are received in `doGet` under a "parameter" property of the first function parameter*

So `e.parameter.name` would be the format.